Sending images from Databricks to Slack - Without a public URL of the image
I am trying to solve the change in the Slack API from files.upload and I can't get it to work. My intention is to share some graphs generated in Databricks and send the images to a Slack channel with a bot user. I am trying to upload the files using the new method files.getUploadURLExternal. Apparently, everything is fine, but I can't get the private URL of the image to use it in the message.
Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks
Old version https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload
https://api.slack.com/messaging/files#uploading_files
I tried Everything, but it does not work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
